# Which option is correct, i am unable to find out difference between top 3 options

Tags: jquery

[image]

I encountered this question and can't figure out what is right answer for it. Help Please.

Answer (score 3):

Actually none of them are right. The answer they are looking for is probably (a), which means every link that has an HREF that *starts* with https. But since they didn't include the protocol string, there's nothing stopping it from matching a URL like `https.wordpress.com` or `https/images/kitten.gif` or somesuch.

Comment: +1 for correct "none of the above" answer :)

Answer (score 1):

According to the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/), it should be option a, BUT that won't help if you are already on a page loaded by https and you have relative links.

Answer (score 1):

This is a question about CSS and regular expressions, though it looks like a jQuery question.  The trick is that RegEx's use the `^` and `$` characters to indicate the beginning and ending of a line, respectively.  Therefore, the `^=` operator would match the beginning of the `href` attribute of the anchor elements, and the right answer is option a.

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is

```
$('a[href^=https]');
```

according to jQuery website..

Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value beginning exactly with a given string.

```
jQuery( "[attribute^='value']" )
```

Answer (score 0):

ok i found it.. Yes the right option is 'a'....

as '^' - will check for initial expression
'$' - will check for exact word https